# Xcode is only showing the logger

Tags: xcode

I'm not sure what has happened but my Xcode is only showing the logger:

[image]

If I click on any `.swift` file it doesn't show up.

I'm running the `Xcode 12 beta`.

Any idea what the problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**View** > **Debug area** > **Hide Debug area**